# how to bring background color dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am making one android app with the help of PhoneGap. Please help me out how i can bring background color dynamically

In HTML5:-

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content" >
        <div class="my_body1">      
            <ul id="table_list_id"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In CSS3:-

```
.my_body1 ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
}

.my_body1 ul {
    width: 100%;
}

.my_body1 ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #525252;
}
```

In jQuery:-

```
  function callXMLConnection() {
    $("#table_list_id").empty();
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "table.html",
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: "",
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find('xyz').each(function () {
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var status = $(this).find('status').text();
                if (status == 'vacant') {
                    var scripts = "<li><a href='#'>" + title + "</a></li>"
                    $("#table_list_id").append(scripts).trigger('create');
                }
                else if (status == 'occupied') {
                    var scripts = "<li><a href='#' >" + title + "</a></li>"
                    $("#table_list_id").append(scripts).trigger('create');
                }
            });
        }

    });
}
$(document).unbind('pageinit').bind('pageinit', function () {
    callXMLConnection();
});
```

I want the background color when the status is vacant then it should be green and when status is occupied then it should be red .

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a helpful line of code to set the background colour using jQuery..

```
$("#table_list_id").css("background-color","YOUR COLOR")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `css` like,

```
var scripts='';
if(status == 'vacant'){              
    scripts = "<li style='background-color:green'><a href='#'>"+title+"</a></li>";
}  
else if(status == 'occupied'){  
    scripts = "<li style='background-color:red'><a href='#'>"+title+"</a></li>";
}
if(scripts){
   $("#table_list_id").append(scripts)
                      .trigger('create');
}
```

**Alternatively,** you can create `class` of `status` like,

**CSS**

```
.vacant{background-color:green} /* green background for vacant class */
.occupied{background-color:red} /* red background for occupied class */
```

**SCRIPT**

```
    ......
    var status = $(this).find('status').text();
    var scripts = "<li class='"+status+"'><a href='#'>" + title + "</a></li>";
    $("#table_list_id").append(scripts).trigger('create');
```

It is **sort and sweet**

Comment: dude u can see the css tht i am creating a box inside tht box all the data is coming tht box background i need to change

Comment: Which box you mean to say that you want to change the background of `.my_body1` or `ul` or `li`?

Comment: .my_body1 ul li { .. }

Comment: @AtulDhanuka test the above I've made changes in it.

Answer (score 1):

To set background color using jQuery by setting CSS property, you can use following code:

```
$("#table_list_id").css("background-color","YOUR COLOR")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

Here is my own answer, in jQuery:

```
$(data).find('xyz').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var status = $(this).find('status').text();
            if (status == 'vacant') {
                var scripts = "<li style='background:#00FF66'><a href='#'>" + title + "</a></li>"
                $("#table_list_id").append(scripts).trigger('create');
            }
            else if (status == 'occupied') {
                var scripts = "<li style='background:#FF0000'><a href='#' >" + title + "</a></li>"
                $("#table_list_id").append(scripts).trigger('create');
            }
});
```